# DBUnit DatabaseUnitRuntimeException

Tags: java, oracle, dbunit

Create test for full dataset export. I'm using Oracle 11g database and after test run i see this:
`org.dbunit.DatabaseUnitRuntimeException: At least one column is required to build a valid select statement. Cannot load data for table=APEX_040000.SYS_IOT_OVER_16977, cols=[], pk=[]`
In database this table is empty and I can't drop it. How can I export all dataset from db?

Answer (score 1):

These are the different types of exports:

```
public class DatabaseExportSample{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    // database connection
    Class driverClass = Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    Connection jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:hsqldb:sample", "sa", "");
    IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(jdbcConnection);

    // partial database export
    QueryDataSet partialDataSet = new QueryDataSet(connection);
    partialDataSet.addTable("FOO", "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL='VALUE'");
    partialDataSet.addTable("BAR");
    FlatXmlDataSet.write(partialDataSet, new FileOutputStream("partial.xml"));

    // full database export
    IDataSet fullDataSet = connection.createDataSet();
    FlatXmlDataSet.write(fullDataSet, new FileOutputStream("full.xml"));

    // dependent tables database export: export table X and all tables that
    // have a PK which is a FK on X, in the right order for insertion
    String[] depTableNames = 
      TablesDependencyHelper.getAllDependentTables( connection, "X" );
    IDataSet depDataset = connection.createDataSet( depTableNames );
    FlatXmlDataSet.write(depDataSet, new FileOutputStream("dependents.xml"));          

  }
}
```

Visit: http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html